# JS: Switch/Case to change className not working

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

So I'm trying to make my first switch/case function and I cannot figure out why it's not working. I've added a console output to test if the case works, and it seems it does, but it never updates the className:

```
function menuSwitch() {
    var menu = document.getElementById("sidebar").className;

    switch(menu) {
        case "on":
            menu.className = "off";
            console.log('Classname should now be "off"')
            break;
        case "off":
            menu.className = "on";
            console.log('Classname should now be "on"')
            break;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o39e05ag/2/

What am I missing? I've tried removing .className from the variable too and nothing. No errors either. The function is also at the very end of my js to make sure nothing interferes (nothing has the same name either).

> **EDIT:** Just pure JS. I'm not looking for jQuery!
>
> **EDIT 2:** Solved. Instead of .className in the var, I needed to define that in the switch after the var and then the same for each case.

Comment: Try `menu.classList.add('on')` or `menu.classList.remove('on')`

Comment: Change this `var menu = document.getElementById("sidebar").className` to this `var menu = document.getElementById("sidebar")`  Basically, you're trying to access the attribute `className` from a String.

Comment: You are adding a property called `className` to a local string.

Comment: @Ele that's what I tried to begin with. Slaawwa, so instead of `console.log('Classname should now be "off"')` I write `menu.classList.remove('on')`? Tried that and still nothing. I see now that the JsFiddle is throwing a fit saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: menuSwitch is not defined  at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):81)`. This doesn't happen in my live enviroment, so the JsFiddle for now seems to be worthless for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `switch()` you are not using `menu` as the reference of the [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element). Instead you are using the `className` which is basically a string. Hence you will not be able to use `menu.className`:

Change

```
var menu = document.getElementById("sidebar").className;
switch(menu) {
```

To

```
var menu = document.getElementById("sidebar");
switch(menu.className) {
```

```js
function menuSwitch() {
  var menu = document.getElementById("sidebar");
  switch(menu.className) {
    case "on":
      menu.className = "off";
      console.log('Classname should now be "off"')
      break;
    case "off":
      menu.className = "on";
      console.log('Classname should now be "on"')
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
.on{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="menuSwitch()">Toggle menu</button>
<div id="sidebar" class="on">
Test
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not interested in using jQuery just yet. Seems like overkill for my project.

Comment: @Strechingmycompetence, the solution is purely on JS. I simply added the jQuery reference mistakenly......removed now...thanks....

Comment: Thanks for the update. This worked! I added "off" as default classname though and 0px for the left property of the class "on". I'm not sure I understand the WHY here though, to me, it's the same only defined at different instances. I guess I need to research more.

Comment: @Strechingmycompetence, you are most welcome....sometimes we all are in the situation that you are now.........that is why we are helping each other in this community.........happy programming :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not the switch statement.
For a modern HTML5 style, use **[classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)**

Try this (see comments):

```js
function menuSwitch() {
  var menu = document.getElementById("sidebar"); // Get the DOM element
  var className = menu.className; // Get the class

 switch(className) {
  case "on":
   menu.classList.remove('on'); // Remove on
            menu.classList.add('off'); // Add off
   console.log('Classname should now be "off"')
   break;
  case "off":
   menu.classList.remove('off');
      menu.classList.add('on');
   console.log('Classname should now be "on"')
   break;
 }
}
```

```css
#sidebar {
 position: fixed;
}

.on {
 left: 0px;
}

.off {
 left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="menuSwitch();">Toggle menu</button>
<div id="sidebar" class="on">
Test
</div>
```

Comment: So.. with classlist, you get an array that can be iterated and thus, it works to define .className in the var, instead of directly on the switch statement and in the cases like in the example I marked as the solution?

Comment: No, classList returns a DOMTokenList, is not an array, but it's similar, it has length and you can iterate. But it doesn't have all the built-in array methods (like map, filter,etc). A DOMTokenList has its own methods, like add, remove, toggle, etc... Check here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList